# Do we need to maintain Each subscription will have unique EventType Or Multiple subscription can have same EventType in Azure EventGrid Domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, .net-core, azure-eventgrid

I am using EventGrid Domain in my project,
I have created One Topic name "AccountService" and
Created 2 subscription( used WebHook endpoint)
SubscriptionName: CR_Account and EventType: CreateAccount and Endpoint: Endpoint1
and
SubscriptionName: UP_Account and EventType: UpdateAccount and Endpoint: Endpoint2

My concern is like can I create one more subscription
SubscriptionName: CRNew_Account and EventType: UpdateAccount and Endpoint: Endpoint3

so that when EventGrid receives Event then it has to trigger both Subscriptions(here "CR_Account" and "CRNew_Account")

Comment: for double check, your subscription *CRNew_Account* is created for EventTpe: *UpdateAccount*?

Comment: I am sorry, CRNew_Account is there with EventType CreateAccount 
My Requirement is publisher need to send the same data to two different endpoint

so I created two subscriptions with the same EventType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AEG supports a **Fan-Out** pattern, where the topic event message is multicast to all its subscribed subscriptions and based on their filtering, the event message is delivered to the destination endpoint in the reliable manner.

In your case, both subscriptions such as *CR_Account* and *CRNew_Account* with a filtering on the EventType *CreateAccount* will received the same topic event message.